# How can I use the avalon wizard?

Tags: wpf

I downloaded the [avalon wizard](http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/) but I can't find anywhere any sample code.

Does anyone know how can I use this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download the sourcecode, it includes samples and documentation.

Comment: :) you are right. I thought that was only the installer and binaries. Source code includes sample as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [original post here.](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/how-to-use-wpf-avalonwizard-control-i/)

1.Create a new window, and in the XAML file, add below markup:

[image]

2.Add some WizardPage in the markup:

[image]

Tips: If your designer do not update after adding the above XAML lines, try to edit the **PageIndex** as shown below, and change it from 0, for instance, to 1 or whatever… This will update the designer view.

[image]

3 By changing the PageIndex in XAML, you can switch to different pages at design time, then drag the WPF controls in the designer or XAML code.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, but the layout has never been updated for Windows 8/10 look, or am I doing something wrong? I have still the blured back button from Vista/Win7 and the title bar is as small as in every normal application window (not with double height like your screenshot shows). Comctl6 is required via manifest.